# Global stable manifold

Tags: dynamical-systems

In Brin Stuck, the following **Corollary 5.6.6** is left as an exercise, that of which I'm not sure on how to prove. The stable-manifold theorem states that there exists $\epsilon >0$ small enough such that *local stable manifolds* $W^s_\epsilon(x) = \{ y \in M: d(f^n(x), f^n(y)) < \epsilon \quad \forall n \geq 0\}$ is a $C^1$ embedded manifold for every $x \in \Lambda$ in the hyperbolic set. Now we're interesting in the *global stable manifold* (defined below). **Proposition 5.6.5** is just a set theoretic result, while the Corollary that follows seems to be a differential geometry question. Note that there is a typo here, authors should have written that $W^s(x)$ is an **immersed** $C^1$ submanifold (not embedded). I'm trying to find a prove for this claim. As a matter of fact, one can see that $W^s(x)$ is defined as a increasing union of embedded $C^1$-manifolds ! I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065636/increasing-union-of-regular-submanifold) where I asked whether or not an increasing sequence of embedded submanifold is still an embedded submanifold. That is not the case, but at the time I thought that the stable manifold was to be a embedded submanifold (following the typo). Therefore, the question remains open as to whether or not such an increasing sequence can end up being an immersed submanifold !

Maybe that's not the way to do it...

Anyway, thanks for the help !

[image]

Comment: A duplicate of [Global stable manifold always an embedded submanifold? Typo or misreading?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464463/global-stable-manifold-always-an-embedded-submanifold-typo-or-misreading).

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I'm asking for a proof/ref of Corollary 5.6.6.

Comment: Please look at the comments and the answer.

Comment: It seems to me these are discussions on the notion of "$C^1$ embedded manifold" used by the authors. In the answer, it says that it means that "*there exists a $C^1$-smooth injective immersion from the open disk (whose image is in the stable manifold)*". If this is the case, there's nothing to prove. I'll bet that the user meant to say "...(whose image **is** the stable manifold)", not the "in". That's the regular definition of a immersed submanifold. We need the all image of the disk to be $W^s(x)$, not just a part of it...If you have a proof, I'll be very thankful if you could provide it !

Comment: I don't have the book at my disposal, but from the discussion under the other question it follows that Corollary 5.6.6 is wrong, provided that the topologies on $W^s(x)$ and $W^u(x)$ are relative topologies inherited from $M$. And this choice of topologies is perfectly natural in a textbook on **dynamics**. The global manifolds are homeomorphic to the unit balls, but when considered with the submanifold topologies (I cannot give a reference now). From the dynamicist's (as opposed to the topologist's) point of view the submanifold topology is rather too fine to be interesting.

Comment: Regarding a reference on your last question, see Morton Brown's PAMS paper [The Monotone Union of Open $n$-Cells is an Open $n$-Cell](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034881?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer both of my questions, even though I'm still a little be confused: but then why do we call it the global stable **manifold** if it's not a manifold at all? I've read in different places that it was a immersed submanifold, so I'm a little bit confused by what you're saying...

Comment: For instance (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506292.pdf) clearly state that the global stable manifold is immersed.

Comment: And this is a standard definition, I think.

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but that also the case in Shub : Global stability of dynamical systems (1967) (see 6.6)

Comment: @LutzL $n$ is just the iteration of the dynamic $f$. $W^s(x)$ is the intersection of the preimage of the $\epsilon-$ball around $f^n(x)$ for all $n$ !

Comment: Oh sorry ! It's for all $n \geq 0$, not just one specific $n$! I'll edit